# Google Cloud Functions trigger-http and trigger-topic unexpectedly runs synchronously

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm puzzled at what we see when running this setup:

- FuncA: Google Cloud Function trigger-http
- FuncB: Google Cloud Function trigger-topic

FuncA is called by a HTTP client. Upon being called, FuncA does some light work setting up a JSON object describing a task to perform, and stores this JSON into Google Cloud Storage. When the file has been written FuncA published a topic with a pointer to the gs file. At this point FuncA responds to the client and exits. Duration typically 1-2 seconds.

FuncB is informed that a topic has been published and is invoked. The task JSON is picked up and work beings. After processing FuncB stores the result info Firebase Realtime Database. FuncB exits at this point. Duration typically 10-20 seconds.

As FuncA and FuncB are in no way associated, live their individual process lifecycles on different function names (and triggers) and only share communication through pub/sub topic message passing (one-direction from A to B) we would expect that FuncA can run again and again, publishing topics at any rate. FuncB should be triggered and fan-out to scale with what ever pace FuncA is called with.

This is however not what happens.

In the logs we see results following this pattern:

- 10:00:00.000 FuncA: Function execution started
- 10:00:02.000 FuncA: Function execution took 2000 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
- 10:00:02.500 FuncB: Function execution started
- 10:00:17.500 FuncB: Function execution took 15000 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
- 10:00:18.000 FuncA: Function execution started
- 10:00:20.000 FuncA: Function execution took 2000 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
- 10:00:20.500 FuncB: Function execution started
- 10:00:35.500 FuncB: Function execution took 15000 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
- ...

The client calling FuncA clearly gets to wait for both FuncA and FuncB to finish, before being let through with the next request. It is expected that FuncA would finish, and allow a new call in immediately at what ever pace the calling client can "throw at it".

Beefing the client up with more threads only repeats this pattern, such that "paired" calls to FuncA->FuncB always waits for each other.

Dicsuss, clarify, ... stackoverflow, do your magic! :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can it be related to the logic in the client-side, maybe the client waiting for an answer from FuncB before making the request again to FuncA? I have just built an example of your scenario with FuncA and FuncB being a couple of HelloWorld samples applications with a sleep(2) and sleep(10) in order to simulate the processing time, and I was not able to reproduce the behavior you explain. I can query FuncA, then FuncB, and then FuncA  before FuncB has finished. It is true that my example does not have the connection between functions, but the inner logic should no affect the behavior.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Perhaps share some representative code of your functions? Also you might consider lightening up FuncA to only write the JSON into GCS and then using the inbuilt GCS PubSub notification to publish to topic: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes